# What does a white skull above the last enemy mean while boarding ships?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

In Assassins Creed Black Flag sometimes I notice a small white skull above one of the last enemies I need to take out to 'win' the boarding of a ship. It doesn't happen all the time and it seems to happen when he comes out from below deck and is one of the last ones you'll need out of the 5.

Just curious as to what this indicates, if anything. It's very peculiar that it's not explained at all in the game.

Answer (score 16):

The white skull icon seems to indicate which enemy is engaging in combat with a crewmate that needs saving and is accompanied by a blue dot over said crewmate in trouble, this skull is to help indicate which enemy to focus on to help save that crewmate.

Comment: After reading this yesterday I paid attention last night and this does indeed seem to be the case though its not always clear.

Comment: Even with its vast database of knowledge about everything even remotely related; I don't think the game actually tells you this. But now that I read it, it sounds somewhat logical.

Comment: You will also hear him shouting for help

Answer (score 1):

That means that one of your crew is in trouble! The white skull means that, that enemy is attacking your crew member, kill him before he kills your mate!